# ¿Cómo mando un array de elementos input en un formulario hacia script PHP con AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, array

Tengo mi formulario:

```
<form id="formulario">
    <input type="date" id="campo1" name="campo[]" placeholder="campo1"> // Envía 2022/11/04
    <input type="date" id="campo2" name="campo[]" placeholder="campo2"> // Envía 2022/11/05
    <input type="date" id="campo3" name="campo[]" placeholder="campo3"> // Envía 2022/11/06
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Como pueden ver todos tiene el mismo "name" como campo[], intente serializar con JQuery

```
$(document).ready( () => {
    $('#formulario').submit( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let datos = $(this).serialize();
        console.log(datos);
    });
});
```

Pero me arroja el resultado con console.log():

```
campo%5B%5D=2022/11/04&campo%5B%5D=2022/11/05&campo%5B%5D=2022/11/06
```

¿Cómo podré detectar en el script PHP a cuál campo estoy requiriendo, supongo que debo mandar como arreglo en lugar de serializar directamente?
En el lado backend con PHP el punto es generar un PDF con DOMPDF (otra tema), el punto es que salga tipo "La primera fecha es: campo[], la segunda fecha es: campo[], la tercera fecha es: campos[]"

Aquí mi duda es como enviarlo de esa manera y como identificar por el apuntador.

Comment: Yo usaria FormData (algo asi como `var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);`) en lugar de serializarlos, y para recogerlos en orden, pues bueno, de hecho ya se envian en orden, tanto serializados como en FormData, y el truco es saberlos recoger en el PHP como un array y tratarlos como tal, donde el primer elemento del array es el primer name, el segundo más de lo mismo, etc

Comment: bueno, no es tan truco, simplemente haces un `$campos = $_REQUEST['campo'];` y luego los recorres con un `foreach($campos as $campo) { // y aqui vas haciendo lo que debas con ellos teniendo en cuenta lo dicho antes, el primero se corresponderá con el primer name, el segundo con el segundo, etc };`

Comment: Es decir por DATA: de AJAX mando la formData y desde PHP con request y variable aplico un foreach ¿Es eso?

Comment: si, pero busca ejemplos del `FormData en ajax de jquery` por la red, pues hay que poner un par de parámetros en false creo para que funcione bien la petición